# ¿Cómo encontrar los JPanel o JFrame desde el código en Apache NetBeans IDE 17?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Estoy trabajando con Apache NetBeans IDE 17 para desarrollar una aplicación de escritorio en Java con Swing. En mi proyecto, tengo varios métodos que manejan eventos de botones, como private void jButtonAdjuntar1ActionPerformed. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma o acceso directo en Apache NetBeans IDE 17 para encontrar fácilmente los JPanel o JFrame correspondientes a estos métodos en el diseñador gráfico, en lugar de tener que buscar manualmente en el código.

En resumen, me gustaría una forma rápida de navegar desde el código a la parte gráfica de la interfaz de usuario en Apache NetBeans IDE 17 para identificar dónde se encuentran los componentes visuales relacionados con los eventos.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o consejo sobre cómo lograr esto de manera eficiente en Apache NetBeans IDE 17. ¡Gracias!

(explicación visual)

1.busco la accion que tenga mi boton, jframe lo que sea

2. le doy click o click derecho o lo que haya

3.me redirige al boton que tiene esa propiedad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya intentaste usar el panel de navegacion? Normalmente aparece bajo el panel de proyecto

Comment: @RuslanLópez Me lleva igualmente al código, yo quiero ir a la interfaz gráfica

Comment: ahh es que primero tienes que estar en la vista diseño

Comment: Ctrl+7, o bien **Window -> Navigator**, te abre un subPanel, le das "click" al elemento y te lleva a la declaración del mismo.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Entonces no estás contestando a mi pregunta, yo quiero saber si desde el CODIGO, por ejemplo dando a un action, ver si tiene una opción para ir a la interfaz gráfica donde se situa

Comment: @MarcePuente Con eso me lleva al metodo, pero yo no quiero eso, yo si estoy encima de ese metodo, por ejemplo el action de un boton, QUE ME LLEVE a su parte gráfica

Comment: @EnriqueVázquez, osea que quieres exactamente lo contrario, no hay forma (que yo sepa) de hacerlo.

Comment: @EnriqueVázquez te recomiendo hacer el recorrido del sitio, este espacio donde me lees no es para responder, por ello es que efectivamente no estoy respondiendo, estoy tratando de que clarifiques tu pregunta ya que tiene demasiadas deficiencias evidentes

Comment: @RuslanLópez Pues es muy fácil de entender, no le veo la complicación, pero vamos lo edito para que lo comprendas visualmente

Comment: @RuslanLópez Recorrido no se si te refieres a que describa lo que quiero hacer o recorrido de ir buscando el código, tu clarificación tambien es "deficiente"

Comment: En la esquina inferior izquierda puedes hallar el link para hacer el recorrido. Avísanos cuando lo hayas completado, y haz las modificaciones pertinentes, por ejemplo las preguntas que piden "la manera mas eficiente" terminan cerradas por estar basadas en opiniones.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Hombre, si yo hago una pregunta será para buscar la más eficiente, de todas formas, lo que me dices del recorrido abajo a la izquierda no me sirve, porque cuando estás en diseño, si que te hace el recorrido, pero te da el recorrido de donde está el item, pero en source solo te enseña donde estan los metodos colocados

Comment: @RuslanLópez Y opiniones yo no estoy dando, si una persona no me está dando lo que estoy buscando en la pregunta, osea una respuesta que no es correcta, si yo estoy buscando melones y me estas señalando sandias no te voy a decir que es eso

Comment: @RuslanLópez Todo esto desde el respeto, un saludo